# Is it possible to configure the search indexer to index a sub directory under fileadmin in typo3?

Tags: search, indexing, typo3

I am storing the file tho be listed in a table in a sub-directory under the fileadmin tree in typo 3. I was wondering whether there is a way to get the search indexer to index this sub-directory, and possibly index the pdf files in said sub directories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After an hour or so of searching... [Yes. As described here](http://xavier.perseguers.ch/tutoriels/typo3/articles/indexed-search-crawler.html)